# SWFupload url callback

Tags: javascript, swfupload

I've seen how others are catching data coming back from their uploader backend. (See: [How do i get swfupload to return image URL after upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296234/how-do-i-get-swfupload-to-return-image-url-after-upload)) But I keep getting a javascript error on .bind(). Any ideas?

Code:
        upload1= new SWFUpload({

```
      // Backend Settings
      upload_url: "uploader2.py",
      post_params: various params,

      // File Upload Settings <a id="printimages" style="float: right">Print Images</a>
      file_size_limit : "100 MB",     // 100MB
      file_types : "",
      file_types_description : "Any File",
      file_upload_limit : 1000,
      file_queue_limit : 0,

      // Event Handler Settings (all my handlers are in the Handler.js file)
      swfupload_preload_handler : preLoad,
      swfupload_load_failed_handler : loadFailed,
      file_dialog_start_handler : fileDialogStart,
      file_queued_handler : fileQueued,
      file_queue_error_handler : fileQueueError,
      file_dialog_complete_handler : fileDialogComplete,
      upload_start_handler : uploadStart,
      upload_progress_handler : uploadProgress,
      upload_error_handler : uploadError,
      upload_success_handler : uploadSuccess,
      upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,

      // Button Settings
      button_image_url : "images/XPButtonUploadText_61x22.png",
      button_placeholder_id : "ButtonPlaceholder1",
      //button_placeholder : "spanButtonPlaceholder1",
      button_width: 61,
      button_height: 22,
      moving_average_history_size: 1,

      // Flash Settings
      flash_url : "swf/swfupload.swf",
      flash9_url : "swf/swfupload_fp9.swf",

       // My settings
      custom_settings : {
        progressTarget : "fsUploadProgress1",
        cancelButtonId : "btnCancel1",
        tdFilesQueued : document.getElementById("tdFilesQueued"),
        tdFilesUploaded : document.getElementById("tdFilesUploaded"),
        tdErrors : document.getElementById("tdErrors"),
        tdCurrentSpeed : document.getElementById("tdCurrentSpeed"),
        tdCurrentFile : document.getElementById("tdCurrentFile"),
        tdAverageSpeed : document.getElementById("tdAverageSpeed"),
        tdMovingAverageSpeed : document.getElementById("tdMovingAverageSpeed"),
        tdTimeRemaining : document.getElementById("tdTimeRemaining"),
        tdTimeElapsed : document.getElementById("tdTimeElapsed"),
        tdPercentUploaded : document.getElementById("tdPercentUploaded"),
        tdSizeUploaded : document.getElementById("tdSizeUploaded"),
        tdProgressEventCount : document.getElementById("tdProgressEventCount")
      },

      // Debug Settings

      debug: false 
   }).bind('uploadSuccess', function(event, file, serverData){ 
      alert(serverData);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

The linked example is using [swfupload jquery plugin](https://github.com/ifunk/swfupload-jquery-plugin) and it has a bind function. Your example is using the plugin without jquery so when you call bind on the new SWFUpload object you got an error because it hasn't got a bind method. The easiest way to make it work is to implement your callback functions.

```
// Backend Settings
upload1= new SWFUpload({
  upload_url: "uploader2.py",
  post_params: various params,

  // File Upload Settings <a id="printimages" style="float: right">Print Images</a>
  file_size_limit : "100 MB",     // 100MB
  file_types : "",
  file_types_description : "Any File",
  file_upload_limit : 1000,
  file_queue_limit : 0,

  // Event Handler Settings (all my handlers are in the Handler.js file)
  swfupload_preload_handler : preLoad,
  swfupload_load_failed_handler : loadFailed,
  file_dialog_start_handler : fileDialogStart,
  file_queued_handler : fileQueued,
  file_queue_error_handler : fileQueueError,
  file_dialog_complete_handler : fileDialogComplete,
  upload_start_handler : uploadStart,
  upload_progress_handler : uploadProgress,
  upload_error_handler : uploadError,
  upload_success_handler : myUploadSuccessHandler,
  upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,

  // Button Settings
  button_image_url : "images/XPButtonUploadText_61x22.png",
  button_placeholder_id : "ButtonPlaceholder1",
  //button_placeholder : "spanButtonPlaceholder1",
  button_width: 61,
  button_height: 22,
  moving_average_history_size: 1,

  // Flash Settings
  flash_url : "swf/swfupload.swf",
  flash9_url : "swf/swfupload_fp9.swf",
  },

  // Debug Settings

  debug: true 
 });

 // your callback 
 function myUploadSuccessHandler (file, serverData){
    alert(file, serverData);
 }
```

Another useful thing is to turn the debug option to true :)